# Most efficient way to store and build data python

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, dataframe

In a loop through many web pages I´m web scraping to get some information:

I´m thinking of building a csv, something like this:

```
fieldnames = ['id', 'variable1', 'variable2']

f= open('file.csv', 'w', newline='')
my_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
my_writer.writeheader()

for webpage in webpages:

  something where I get the information and put it in a dictionary mydict.
  Example mydict={'id':1, 'variable1':200, 'variable2':300}   

   writer.writerow(mydict)

f.close()
```

The problem is that there may be different number of variables in each webpage, so I would need a modification to this.

The other alternative I´m think of is to create a list of dictionaries, and at the end convert it to a dataframe and to a csv:

```
finalist =[]
for webpage in webpages:
    
    something where I get the information and put it in a dictionary mydict.
    Example mydict={'id':1, 'variable1':200, 'variable2':300}     

    mylist =[mydict]
    finalist.extend(mylist)

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.to_csv()
```

It is a very long loop so there will be a lot of rows, so which of the two would be more efficient?. Or there is another way more efficient than these two? Also, should I keep a json file or a csv or any other format to store the data at the end in order to be used latter on R or any other program?

Comment: What kind of data you are storing? Choice of the data-structure is entirely based on the format of the raw-data and what you intend to do with that data. Here you have not provided both.

Comment: The data at the end will be used to do some statistical analysis (regressions, etc)  probably in R. The data just have some headers and rows for the values.